# how to create dynamic facebook tabs?

Tags: php, json, facebook

i run a website where people have their own subpages like http://www.url.com/me.php?=username or http://username.url.com

i've been reading at http://www.bentedder.com/creating-custom-facebook-page-tabs-that-load-external-urls/ on how to create custom tabs that users can then add to their facebook pages.

now, it works if I redirect users to:

```
http://www.url.com
```

but I can't get it to work so that each user can redirect to their profile at:

```
http://username.url.com
```

is there any way possible to achieve this?

UPDATE: I tried to get the tabs working like this via JSON:

```
www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=https://www.url.com/me.php&app_data={"username":"joe"}
```

and then retrieve it via:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];
var_dump($signed_request);
var_dump($app_data);
```

That doesn't work either :( It shows all the variables like 'algorithm', etc. EXCEPT the app_data. I'm sure I am doing something wrong somewhere but I can't figure out what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be clear on the question, but I think your issue lies within the set up on facebook.  For a tab or page to appear within a facebook page or tab it must be included as a domain in the app settings.  Bear in mind that almost everything you add to facebook is called an "app" by them.  An extra tab is an "app" and so forth.

I did notice, but I am sure that it is simply an example that you are using that you are using the http protocol and not the https protocol.  Facebook pretty much demands that all pages and sites that are used in this way use SSL.  Just a sub-thought.

Comment: Yep, I tried that ...and I did it with https indeed. For example, if my URL is http://www.url.com/me.php?username=joe then I make the URL as http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=0123456789&next=https://www.url.com/me.php?username=joe and the tab gets added correctly, but it only adds https://www.url.com/me.php without the username, so it's not really working.

Comment: What if you did all the work server side and then used a frame or div to display the subdomain.  That way the app would always be showing abc.com and the page on abc.com would contain a frame of john.abc.com

Comment: I tried doing it server side with a request like https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.my_url.com/me.php&app_data=joe where supposedly you can pass "app_data" as a custom variable and then retrieve it later to show the correct page. It works fine but it just gets redirected to me.php on my website and even though the signed request is displayed, it doesn't contain "app_data" variable :(